# Data is not loading in react table when i see it in safari browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

my data in react table is not loading in safari browser. the page ( part of react table ) goes blank and when you scroll a little bit, it shows the header of the table & that is it for the page. i have atttached a snippet for the same.

PS - i am using fuse theme also

pls find the link for the snippet -  https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRCR3.png

Comment: I think you forgot/missed to add the snippet

Comment: @kunambi, i have added the link for the snippet now, pls check

Comment: Please add your code here, not an image.

Comment: It is fixed now, the issue was with the table css as the header was taking up all the space